# Is it needed to use `cache.close()` after finishing using cache in Django Views?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-cache, django-caching

I found [cache.close()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.cache.close) saying below in [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/). *I'm learning [Django Cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/):

> You can close the connection to your cache with close() if implemented by the cache backend.

So, I use `cache.close()` after I finish using cache in Django Views as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.core.cache import cache

def test(request):
    cache.set("name", "John")
    cache.set("age", 36)

    print(cache.get("first_name")) # John
    print(cache.get("age")) # 36
    
    cache.close() # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

My questions:

1. Is it needed to use `cache.close()` after finishing using cache in Django Views?
2. If `cache.close()` is not used after finishing using cache in Django Views, are there anything bad?

Answer (score 1):

no, see django/core/cache/__init__.py:

```py
def close_caches(**kwargs):
    # Some caches need to do a cleanup at the end of a request cycle. If not
    # implemented in a particular backend cache.close() is a no-op.
    caches.close_all()


signals.request_finished.connect(close_caches)
```

if the request finishes, all caches are closed.

I think it is for management commands or thirdparty integrations.